# Height of tile with discrete values in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a heat map for one year (2014) for about a 180 countries where the fill is GHG emissions. The y axis is supposed to be the countries and the x axis is supposed to be the year. Following is the code I am using,

```
g<-ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = Country, fill = `GHG_Emissions_Per_Capita_w_LULUCF_(tCO2e)`)) +
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_gradient2(low = colors[1],
                                     mid = colors[paletteSize/2],
                                     high = colors[paletteSize], 
                                     midpoint = (max(data$`GHG_Emissions_Per_Capita_w_LULUCF_(tCO2e)`)+min(data$`GHG_Emissions_Per_Capita_w_LULUCF_(tCO2e)`)) / 2,
                                     name = "Total GHG w LULUCF")
```

I am facing 2 problems,
1. The names on the y axis overlap and I cannot seem to make the y axis longer or the tiles higher to accommodate the name
2. The x axis is supposed to be one discrete element "2014" which gets split into a continuous variable.

Here is the output of `str(data)`

```
'data.frame':   191 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Country                                   : chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Andorra" ...
 $ Year                                      : int  2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 2014 ...
 $ GHG_Emissions_Per_Capita_wo_LULUCF_(tCO2e): num  1.02 3.13 5.17 6.54 5.86 ...
 $ GHG_Emissions_Per_Capita_w_LULUCF_(tCO2e) : num  1.02 3 5.16 6.27 9.36 ...
```

Here is some sample data.

```
                       Country Year GHG_Emissions_Per_Capita_wo_LULUCF_(tCO2e) GHG_Emissions_Per_Capita_w_LULUCF_(tCO2e)
1                  Afghanistan 2014                                  1.0185643                                 1.0185643
2                      Albania 2014                                  3.1277710                                 3.0039601
3                      Algeria 2014                                  5.1667095                                 5.1564317
4                      Andorra 2014                                  6.5401349                                 6.2655871
5                       Angola 2014                                  5.8623365                                 9.3643598
6            Antigua & Barbuda 2014                                 11.4753630                                11.5420209
7                    Argentina 2014                                  8.1115625                                10.3127052
8                      Armenia 2014                                  2.9682122                                 2.9177457
9                    Australia 2014                                 25.1371295                                22.3016710
10                     Austria 2014                                  8.7978737                                 8.2251670
11                  Azerbaijan 2014                                  7.6137557                                 6.7257221
12                Bahamas, The 2014                                  7.1029869                                 8.1139307
```

This is a screenshot of the plot I am trying to make

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal data sample to reproduce the issue ? This would help people to be able to answer this question more quickly. If it requires a lot of data, can you reproduce with a data set that is already part of R or some R package?

Comment: to 1., add a theme with a font size smaller than default. `+ theme_grey(8)1 for example. TO answer two, we need some sample data. Please provide the output of `str(data)` or `dput(head(data))` and add it to your question.

Comment: You can just use `factor(year)`, or have a look at `scale_x_date` for more detailed labeling options.

Comment: Thanks, Both the theme_grey() and factor(year) worked.